# How to restart a .py file when it finishes

Tags: python

I am creating a simple game that will have the character die a lot, and as a consequence will end the game. how can i make it to have something like pressing the space bar restarts the file or something along those lines? It's a very simple file, so i am just looking for a simple solution.

Comment: What's your code? What did you tried?

Comment: It is a choose your own adventure game. so it mailny just has if statements, like i said, very simple, it's my first projects. i typed the while true statement but the while was the function orange instead of that light blue. what is it?

Comment: I haven't tried anything except for the code that Randi-Revenath sent me, and that just caused errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your script in a

```
while True:
    ...
```

block, or with a bash script:

```
while true ; do
    yourpythonscript.py
```

Comment: um yeah i tried this but it just added 4 errors to the code, does this work with yours?

Comment: and what does the do do? its a variable so i wouldn't expect it to work as anything but.